# Trigonometry, simple though I confused

Tags: trigonometry

If $3\sec^2\theta+\tan\theta=7$, $$\frac{\operatorname{cosec}(2\theta) + \cos \theta}{\sin(2\theta) + \cot \theta}=?$$

Comment: Are we looking at $\operatorname{cosec}(2\theta) + \frac{\cos \theta}{\sin(2\theta)} + \cot \theta$, or $\frac{\operatorname{cosec}(2\theta) + \cos \theta}{\sin(2\theta) + \cot \theta}$?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! The community here prefers/expects questions to include something of what the asker knows about the problem. (*What have you tried? Where did you get stuck?* etc) This information helps answerers tailor their responses to best serve you, without wasting time (theirs or yours) explaining things you already know; it can also reduce confusion due to formatting ambiguities such as the one suggested in the first comment. (It also helps convince people that you aren't simply trying to get them to do your homework for you.)

Comment: Basically you remind us of our classmates in high school.

Answer (score 1):

$$3\sec^2x+\tan x-7=0 \implies 3\tan^2 x+\tan x-4=0 \implies \tan x=1,-4/3$$ 
First take $x=\pi/4$
$$\implies F(x)=\csc 2x+\frac{\cos x}{\sin 2x}+\cot x =1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+1=2+ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$$
Next $x=\tan^{=1}(-4/3) \implies \sin x=-4/5~ or~ cos x=-3/5$ and proceed similarly.

Answer (score 0):

Your equation is equivalent to
$$
\frac{3}
{{\cos ^2 \theta }} + \frac{{\sin \theta }}
{{\cos \theta }} = 7
$$
From it you get
$$
3\left( {\sin ^2 \theta  + \cos ^2 \theta } \right) + \sin \theta \cos \theta  = 7\cos ^2 \theta 
$$
which is equivalent to
$$
3\sin ^2 \theta  + \sin \theta \cos \theta  - 4\cos ^2 \theta  = 0
$$
Now you have
$$
3\tan ^2 \theta  + \tan \theta  - 4 = 0
$$
which has the solutions $\tan \theta=1$ and $\tan \theta=-4/3$. From these you can get the values of $\cos \theta$ and $\sin \theta$ and so you can calculate the second expression.
Since 
$$
\tan \theta  =  - \frac{4}
{3}
$$
you have that $\sin \theta= -\frac{4}{3}\cos \theta$. Now you have
$$
\left\{ \begin{gathered}
  \sin \theta  =  - \frac{4}
{3}\cos \theta  \hfill \\
  \sin ^2 \theta  + \cos ^2 \theta  = 1 \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right.
$$
whence you get the required values.

Comment: Sir can you show the next step,  how to get the values of cos θand sine θ

Comment: Yes, just one moment